# Doubt in proof of If $\alpha(s)$ is a planar curve $\iff \tau = 0, \tau $ is torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

If $\alpha(s)$ is a planar curve $\iff  \tau = 0, \tau $ is torsion.

Can you tell me is my proof correct?

Let normal to plane be $ \vec V$. As it is planar curve $\vec V = \vec c$, a constant vector

We know that Tangent $\vec T$ and normal $\vec N$ to $\alpha(s)$ are normal to each other and also perpendicular to $\vec V$

Binormal $\vec B = \vec T \times \vec N = b\vec V$, where b is constant

$\frac{d \vec B}{ds} = b \frac{d\vec V}{dx} = \vec 0$ as $\vec V $ is constant vector

i.e., $\tau = 0$

Is this proof correct? in text book i see a much more detailed proof...Pls correct me if i am going wrong

Comment: You've proved only the easy direction (assuming you actually justify that $\vec T$ and $\vec N$ are orthogonal to $\vec V$). Now how do you prove that a curve with $\tau=0$ lies in some plane?

Comment: Sir i took a plane with normal $\vec V$ and a curve $\alpha(s)$. $\vec T, \vec N$ are tangent and normal to curve $\alpha$. So T, N are in that plane with normal $\vec V$. Binormal $\vec B$ is in direction of $\vec V$. so $\tau$ with be that related to that plane right. It looks implicit. Any mistake? I could not understand what u r pointint to ... pls elaborate